# Filtering by distance vs. field value in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a schema which includes a maximum radius for a result to show up - for example, 50. I am able to calculate distance and filter by that without problem, but I really need to filter by that field, which changes from document to document. I've tried:

```
fq={!frange l=0 u=radius_field}geodist()
```

and

```
fq={!func}geodist():[0 TO radius_field]
```

to no effect. Is there any way to do this? I could filter client-side, worst case, but I figure there's somebody out there who has had the same use case.

Comment: Similar to this unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8348407/399704

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but could you create a new function `is_in_range(radius_field)` that returns a boolean result if the `geodist()` is less than the `radius_field` parameter?  This might circumvent the issues you are finding with trying to filter by a range using a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I'll look into that if I don't get a direct answer.

Comment: @CoreyBrown Were you ever able to get this to work? I am trying to set the radius from a field and am having a hard time finding an answer as well. (I do not know how to build solr functions like Aaron D suggested)

Comment: @Coyote6 - never to my satisfaction. I did get something working, but it was about the same speed as the solution I was comparing Solr's speed against (a MySQL stored procedure), so the project was discarded. Another idea was to map every zip code in the US to every other zip code by distance and just have a big mapping table that then feeds into Solr.

Comment: @CoreyBrown Gotcha, this is what I was doing with mine: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234687/find-lat-long-points-w-different-radius-per-point

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but I think I got it to work without a custom function.  I know this is old, but wanted to post in case someone else is looking.

```
fq={!frange l=0 h=12742}sub(radius_field,geodist(field,point))
```

The 12742 is the diameter of the earth in km as I still needed a hard number for that, but I doubt most are searching in space.  So basically we subtract the distance from radius_field to find out if it is in range.

radius_field - distance

If the results are a positive number than it is within range. If it is a negative number than it is not. Please let me know if I screwed up my logic. Thanks.