# Solr Distance Filter from a Radius Field

Tags: solr, filter, geolocation

Hi I am very new to Solr queries (like a few hours), so please excuse me if this is a naive question, but is there a way on the geo filter to set the radius from a field.

```
{!geofilt pt=35.3459327,-97.4705935 sfield=locs_field_location$latlon d=fs_radius}
```

Or do a subquery to return the value of that field `fs_field_job_search_radius` and place it in there. I can return the value from the field list so I was hoping it could go in there, in some method.

This is similar to this [Filtering by distance vs. field value in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394555/filtering-by-distance-vs-field-value-in-solr) but I do not know if he got it working or where I would need to start to write a function as was suggested.  Also this is on a Solr server I do not control. It is controlled by my hosting company, so I do not know if I can even create functions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Took a work around, but I got what I was trying to accomplish I believe.

```
fq={!frange l=0 h=12742}sub(radius_field,geodist(field,point))
```

The 12742 is the diameter of the earth in km as I still needed a hard number for that, but I doubt most are searching in space. So basically we subtract the distance from radius_field to find out if it is in range.

radius_field - distance

If the results are a positive number than it is within range. If it is a negative number than it is not. Please let me know if I screwed up my logic. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the h parameter. `fq={!frange l=0}sub(RADIUS_FIELD, geodist(LATLON_FIELD, LAT, LON))` returns the rows that have the Point(LAT,LON) in their ranges.

Comment: Cool I will have to test that out when I get back to that project.  I appreciate it.